# Facebook PHP API : Getting posts in my group

Tags: php, facebook, api, graph, feed

I need to get all the posts in my own group (admin privileges).

I understand that I need "user_managed_groups" permission for myself. I just cant understand how to submit app for review while I cant read feed without permission! I need to do something with test users?

What are the steps I need to follow for app review?

Thanks!

Comment: _“What are the steps I need to follow for app review?”_ - step 1: You start by reading the rather extensive documentation Facebook provides around the whole review process.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921 still applies (with the added limitation now, that your app needs to be in dev mode.)

Comment: In developer mode I can give myself any permission?

Comment: It's a simple question. Just - how do I get a right token with user_managed_groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: app into development mode

Step 2: turn off the "Require secret key" in Advanced settings of the group

Step 3: graph api explorer choose THE app

Step 4: get User access token for YOU (admin of that GROUP and admin of the APP), with permission "user managed groups", then approve it to give that data (in the upcoming popup window)

Step 5: reference in GET: {id of your group}

Step 6: press sumbit

You get JSON response with data on your group